# passing multiple text box values to different view using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, razor

I have two views. In view1 I few have text boxes to enter basic details. once the customer enters basic details and clicks add more details I need to pass the details entered in view1 should pass to the view2 textbox. I tried passing like below but the only email is displaying inside the textbox in view2, not the other 2 values. I can see all the 3 values are passing to the next view in URL but I am not able to display all the values inside their respective textboxes. any suggestion, please.

View 1 :

```js
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var email = document.getElementById('Email').value;
            var firstname = document.getElementById('FirstName').value;
            var lastname = document.getElementById('LastName').value;
            var queryString = "?email=" + email + "&firstname=" + firstname + "&lastname=" + lastname;
            window.location.href = "Home/View2" + queryString;
        }
    </script>
```

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("View1", "Application", FormMethod.Post)) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="col aligncenter">          
        <div class="form-row topMargin">               
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)                    
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirsttName)                    
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName)
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-9 form-group text-right">
                <button class="btn" type="button" id="add" name="add" value="add"  onclick="myFunction();">Add</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 form-group text-right">
                <button class="btn" type="submit" name=new" value="new">view old</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

View 2 :

```js
        window.onload = function () {
            var url = document.location.href,
                params = url.split('?')[1].split('&'),
                data = {}, tmp;
            for (var i = 0, l = params.length; i < l; i++) {
                tmp = params[i].split('=');
                data[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
            }
            document.getElementById("Email").value = data.email;
            document.getElementById("FirstName").value = data.firstname;
                        document.getElementById("LastName").value = data.lastname;
        }
```

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("View2", "Application", FormMethod.Post)) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="col aligncenter">          
        <div class="form-row topMargin">               
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)                    
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirsttName)                    
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName)
             </div>
<div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.address)
             </div>
<div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.state)
             </div>
<div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.zip)
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-9 form-group text-right">
                <button class="btn" type="submit" value="osubmit">submit</button>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In form1's button click event
txtbox.text = form2.txtbox.text

In form2's button click event
txtbox.text = form3.txtbox.text

Comment: I did not understand.